# Cómo transformar HTML a código Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Básicamente tengo este código HTML:

```
  <body>
    <div1>hola
      <div2>radiola1</div2>
      <div3>radiola2</div3>
    </div1>
  </body>
```

Pero solo logro hacer esto con código Javascript:

```
var div1 = document.createElement('div1');
var div2 = document.createTextNode('div2');
var div3 = document.createTextNode('div3');
document.body.appendChild(div1);
document.body.appendChild(div2);
document.body.appendChild(div3);
```

Al hacerlo así los DIVs no quedan anidados. Qué tengo que hacer para anidar etiquetas en javascript?

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 1):

Para que queden anidados deben tener la relación apropiada entre sí. Este código es un ejemplo. La parte que interesa es la que está dentro de la función `myFunction`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var div1 = document.createElement('div');

      var div2 = document.createElement('div')
      div2.appendChild(document.createTextNode('radiola1'));

      var div3 = document.createElement('div')
      div3.appendChild(document.createTextNode('radiola2'));

      div1.appendChild(div2);
      div1.appendChild(div3);

      document.body.appendChild(div1);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Página de pruebas</h1>
  <p id="demo">Prueba:</p>
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Probar código</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Los nodos los creas con `document.createElement` y luego los adicionas al elemento en el que van con el método `appendChild`.

Al pulsar el botón te adiciona los elementos al final del documento. La primera vez quedan después del `<button>`.

Answer (score 0):

Para que `div2` y `div3` queden anidados dentro de `div1`, necesitas agregarlos a `div1` (*no al `body`*)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
var div1 = document.createElement('div1');
div1.innerText = 'hola';
var div2 = document.createElement('div2');
div2.innerText = 'radiola1';
var div3 = document.createElement('div3');
div3.innerText = 'radiola2';

div1.appendChild(div2);
div1.appendChild(div3);
document.body.appendChild(div1);
```

```css
div1 {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
div2 {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
div3 {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, ahora lo tengo claro